# FFmpeg, access violation on av_frame_free when running though Unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I'm working on a video recording plugin for Unity using ffmpeg. I'm new to the video encoding domain and just got my code to work today. But I think a might have a few memory leaks and trying to fix them crashes Unity.

The plugin is written i c++ (as external "C" code) and imported in a c# script in unity with a simple DllImport. Again, this is not my comfort area either, but it works.

When a screen buffer is rendered, I put in a RGB24 buffer and send it to my c++ function, this one:

```
int encode_frame(uint8_t* rgb24Data)
{
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame)
        return COULD_NOT_ALLOCATE_FRAME;

    frame->format = codec_context->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = codec_context->width;
    frame->height = codec_context->height;

    int ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, codec_context->width, codec_context->height, codec_context->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0)
        return COULD_NOT_ALLOCATE_PIC_BUF;

    SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(codec_context->width, codec_context->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codec_context->width, codec_context->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0, 0, 0, 0);


    uint8_t * inData[1] = { rgb24Data };
    int inLinesize[1] = { 3 * codec_context->width };

    sws_scale(ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, codec_context->height, frame->data, frame->linesize); // From RGB to YUV

    frame->pts = frame_counter++;

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ERROR_ENCODING_FRAME_SEND;

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, &pkt);
        if (!ret)
        {
            if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts, codec_context->time_base, video_st->time_base);
            if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, codec_context->time_base, video_st->time_base);

            av_write_frame(outctx, &pkt);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
        else if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {
            frame->pts = frame_counter++;
            ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, frame);
            if (ret < 0)
                return ERROR_ENCODING_FRAME_SEND;
        }
        else if (ret < 0)
            return ERROR_ENCODING_FRAME_RECEIVE;
        else
            break;
    }

    // This one
    av_frame_free(&frame);
}
```

Now, this code might have a lot of issues that I'm not aware of, and you are free to point them out if you like. But the line that gives me error is  `av_frame_free(&frame);`.

If I run this in a synthetic test app in c++ that I made, it works. I can even run it in a c# synthetic test app (exactly like the c++ one), and it works. But if I run it though Unity, it crashes on the first frame. The log says "Read from location fe7f8097 caused an access violation.".

I have tried with `av_freep()` and `av_free()`. Not sure exactly what makes them different (different example codes use different ones), but none work.

So, what I'm I missing? The `frame` is leaking if I don't free it right? But why does it crash in Unity?

The whole thing works great in Unity if I don't have the `av_frame_free(&frame);`. Resulting video looks great!

PS. I'm aware (as far as I know) that the frame also leaks if something fails and returns an error code. But one thing at a time.

Comment: You encode same frame several times for some reason - that seems wrong but shouldn't cause crashes. I don't see anything else wrong with this code. As an idea which couldn't hurt - try using `av_frame_get_buffer` instead of `av_image_alloc`, maybe it'll help.

Comment: Well according to https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavc__encdec.html; "The AVERROR(EAGAIN) return value means that new input data is required to return new output. In this case, continue with sending input". I should send more frames at a time.

Comment: Er, no. It just means that you got everything encoder had to give so far. You should continue sending *new* frames when you have them, not resend frame you already sent. There should be exactly one `avcodec_send_frame` call in this function.

Comment: Thank you for that! Did not realize I read it wrong. I have fixed it now and the problem was probably that the `frame` data was not ready to be released before the encoding was done. Because when I reused the `frame` object and only de-allocated it after the encoding was done (`avcodec_receive_packet89()` returned `NULL`), it worked!

Comment: According to documentation it shouldn't be the case; but at least one encoder has a bug with non-refcounted data (h264_qsv). Thus my suggestion regarding use of `av_frame_get_buffer` - that will make your image data refcounted and more uncoupled from `frame` object; that may also make everything faster.